# I cannot change image in picturebox c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have made a yatzy game in a console application, and I am currently trying to make one in a forms application.
This is what I have so far:

```
namespace Yatzy
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public static Random kast = new Random();

       public static int kast1 = kast.Next(1, 7);
       public static int kast2 = kast.Next(1, 7);
       public static int kast3 = kast.Next(1, 7);
       public static int kast4 = kast.Next(1, 7);
       public static int kast5 = kast.Next(1, 7);
       public static int kast6 = kast.Next(1, 7);


       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }


       private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (kast1 == 1)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning1.png"); 
           }
           else if (kast1 == 2)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning2.png");
           }
           else if (kast1 == 3)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning3.png");
           }
           else if (kast1 == 4)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning4.png");
           }
           else if (kast1 == 5)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning5.png");
           }
           else if (kast1 == 6)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning6.png");
           }
           else
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning0.png");
           }
       }


   }
}
```

As you can see, I define the "kast1" and such in the form, and depending on the outcome, it should display different images in the picturebox. I have looked at every post I could find, and all of the solutions were fuss.

I have tried without "this." and I've tried with "= image.FromFile("Pics\terning#.png");"
Nothing works.

Comment: Nothing works meaning? What happens? any error?

Comment: There are no errors, the image simply doesn't change in the imagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use Bitmap object just to load images in the PictureBox.Perhaps the more cleaner way of loading images is by using the `Load Method of PictureBox`.

If I assume the images are in same directory as your application,enclosed in another folder,this would have done the job easily;

```
this.pictureBox_terning1.Load(@"\Pics\terning1.png");
```

The `Load` method requires a valid path that points to an image as argument,and with this there is no need to call `Refresh` after loading each image.It doesn't matter if the path is absolute or relative,but the thing that matters is that the path should point to an image.
But I would suggest you to create an absolute path to your executable like this;

```
string apppath=Application.StartupPath;
string imagepath=@"\Pics\terning1.png";
this.pictureBox_terning1.Load(apppath+imagepath);
```

As you mentioned that even if no errors are encountered,the images are not being loaded,for such a case debugging would be an ideal technique to find where the program runs out of order.

Comment: Just to make sure, the apppath would be "bin/release" or "bin/debug", depending on what I choose to do. Correct?

Comment: @user2764591 If you are running in `Debug` configuration the `apppath` will be `directory...\bin\Debug` and if configuration is `Release` it will be `directory...\bin\Release`.

Comment: Scrap what I just wrote, I found the problem by debugging/using my head properly. The image only shows up when I click the imageBox*, which wasn't something I wanted originally, but can now use as a feature. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2764591 Glad to see it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call Refresh() on the picturebox control after you change picture source.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the images you want to load are not at the path you are looking at.

```
 image.FromFile("Pics\terning#.png");
```

Expects that your images reside in {youprojectfolder}\bin\DebugORRelease\Pics.

```
new Bitmap(@"\Pics\terning1.png");
```

Expects that you images reside in {most likely c:}\Pics.

So i would suggest to check this first and if this does not work add a Breakpoint (F9) and start debugging (F5) [see MSDN for an introduction in debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I would also suggest you to replace your if, else if construct with a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, which I have tried and works(it will get the bin directory of your app then you can replace folders with image directory):

```
  private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string path1 = path.Replace(@"\bin\Debug\", @"\Pics\");

           if (kast1 == 1)
           {
               this.pictureBox_terning1.Image = new Bitmap(path1 + "terning1.png"); 
           }
           //rest of the code
        }
```

And if you dont like replacing then set your pictures to be copied to bin directory by

> right clicking on image -> properties -> Copy to output directory -> copy
>   always

.